# starting postgres container with persistant volume [docker compose]

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with my database container, so I want to mount an existant database(from host) to the generated container (with docker-compose). I will show you the important part of the yaml file :

```
postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
        ports:
        - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
        - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

So, when I build and turn on docker-compose, postgres container  exited:

[image]

If I remove the persistant volume, it wokrs ! I have also tested with mysql, mongodb -> same issue.

Could you light me up ?

Thanks.

Comment: First thing to do is to check the logs (docker logs <container-id>). There may be something interesting to explain what's happening there. Otherwise, I usually try to run the image using a shell and then try to figure out what's wrong. In this case, you could run `docker run -v data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass --rm -it postgres bash`

From there you can try to start the postgres daemon just as if docker were not involved, and at that point your question becomes a postgres question (rather than a docker one).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I have just shared the way out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this matter and I want to share it. In fact, for getting our container turns on after ' docker-compose up '  command, we should add tty and command arguments like :

```
postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
        ports:
        - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
        - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        tty: true
        command: /bin/bash
```

I hope that  would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to named volumes that can also be reused across multiple services, and are easily retrieved and inspected using the docker command line...

1. First create volume
   `docker volume create db-data`
2. Now modify your yml file

```
    services
        postgres:
            image: postgres
            environment:
                POSTGRES_USER: user
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
            ports:
            - "5432:5432"
            volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
       db-data:
```

3. You can inspect the volume
   `docker volume inspect db-data`

Source: [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)